# Can I mark first and last element of a longtable using fancyhdr dictionary style headers?

Tags: tables, longtable, fancyhdr

After successufully using fancyhdr to mark first and last word on each page, I tried applying the same to a dictionary inside a longtable. However, it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything preventing me to mark table elements in headers?

The example below is a modification of a working tex where `\dictentry{word}{definition}{grammar}` works perfectly, but not when applied to a table cell.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\small{\textbf{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\small{\textbf{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\newcommand\dictentry[1]{
    \large
    #1
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\thinit}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\thnoninit}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{#1}}}

\tolerance=8000

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{3cm}
            
            {Anenex X:}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            
            {List of elements}
            
            \vfill
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

    \begin{longtable}{
        |>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4.28cm}|
        p{4.5cm}|
        p{2.2cm}|
    }
        \hline
        \thinit{Entry:} & \thnoninit{Definition:} & \thnoninit{Grammar:}
        \\ \hline
        \endhead

        \dictentry{\textbf{word 1}} & \emph{some definition} & {grammar}
        \\ \hline

        \dictentry{\textbf{word 2}} & \emph{some definition} & {grammar}
        \\ \hline

    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good idea, done.

Comment: `p` columns are parboxes and  marks have to be at the top level not inside a box. But I don't see why your first column needs to be a p column if it is just a single word

Comment: your document doesn't compile for me, I don't have your font and you don't load longtable and array.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, I have updated and tested the code, it compiles now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know how can I manually set width of columns other than by using `p`, `m` or `b`.

Comment: as David said: use l-type in the first column. You can force a width, but e.g. setting it in the head: `\newcommand{\thinit}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|p{4.28cm}|}{\textbf{#1}}}`.

Comment: you can use `w` but why do you want to set the width rather than let it fit the natural width of the widest entry?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because my data is generated elsewhere and passed to XeLaTeX which, depending on specific data, sometimes produces overflows, inconsistent output format, and weird table behavior. Plus I am not experienced with LaTeX, so I modified solutions that worked for me.

Comment: With @UlrikeFischer's suggestion indeed the marks get into the page. But `\rightmark` (or `\topmark` in TeX's internals) doesn't come out correctly. I assume this might have something to do with `longtable` changing the output routine. @DavidCarlisle can you shed some light on this?

Comment: I would be happy to accept an answer that showed the smallest modification possible to get this to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not use longtable, as it seems to destroy the marks, even if you get them out of the `\parbox`.
So I would just set each entry separately in a one-row `tabular`.
The headers on each page can be added with `\afterpage`.

Also I would recommend not using horizontal and vertical lines. I think this would give a cleaner layout. But to stay close to your example, I give here a solution with the lines.

I have made the page height lower for the demo, so that I don't have to give a long list of words.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, headheight=15pt, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight = 10cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\small{\textbf{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\small{\textbf{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\thinit}[1]{{\centering\textbf{#1}}}

\tolerance=8000

% Header stuff

\newcommand{\Header}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4.28cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{2.2cm}|}
    \hline
    \thinit{Entry:} & \thinit{Definition:} & \thinit{Grammar:} \\
%    \thinit{Entry:} & \thinit{Definition:} & \thinit{Grammar:}\\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

% \afterpage stuff

\newcommand{\APcommand}{\Header\setAP}
\newcommand{\setAP}{\afterpage{\APcommand}}
\newcommand{\clearAP}{\renewcommand{\APcommand}{}}

% Enntries

\newcommand{\entry}[3]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4.28cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{2.2cm}|}
    \large \textbf{#1} & \emph{#2} & #3 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
  \\[-2ex]
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{3cm}
            
            {Anenex X:}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            
            {List of elements}
            
            \vfill
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

\newpage

    \APcommand

    \entry{word1}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word2}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word3}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word4}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word5}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word6}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word7}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word8}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word9}{some definition}{grammar} 

    \entry{word10}{some definition}{grammar}

    \entry{word11}{some definition}{grammar}

    \entry{word12}{some definition}{grammar}

    \clearAP

\end{document}
```

[image]